# How to say someone "feels distant"

Tags: word-requests

I've looked through ALC and Jisho but I couldn't find a good expression to convey that someone feels "distant" especially in a romantic setting.

The best word that I found in Jisho/ALC  was [よそよそしい](https://jisho.org/search/%E3%82%88%E3%81%9D%E3%82%88%E3%81%9D%E3%81%97%E3%81%84). Does this work for the nuance of a romantic partner who doesn't seem to be him/herself?

Comment: Please venture your best guess. Otherwise it just feels like a translation. https://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=feel+distant

Comment: I should have added that from the beginning. I tried よそよそしい which was the best example I could find but it didn't seem to down as I had hoped in conversation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"よそよそしい"is a common word!
We use it like...
「彼女が大好きなので、気を引くためにわざとよそよそしい態度をした」
「友だちが急によそよそしくなった。嫌われたのかな？」